# Handle the close event via task bar

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, windows-7

I am developing a WPF application. I usually close applications via task bar. When we put the mouse on task bar, it will show a preview of the application. I will press the center mouse button on that preview, so the application will close.

This scenario not working in WPF applications. It will send the application to background (GUI will exit, but application still run on background). The only option I have is to handle the `OnClosing()` event. Is there any other method?

[image: Sample image]

Comment: I don't think there is any difference in the handling of events and I am not familiar with this kind of closing an application. Are you sure this isn't done by a third party tool?

Comment: I don't get the whole task bar thing here. Does it matter how the app is closed? The X button in the window doesn't reproduce the same issue?

Comment: This totally smells like a background thread not being shut down.

Comment: if you are talking about center (rotating wheel) press, then it should open new instance of same application in case of windows.

Comment: @AshokRathod You are right, I am said this scenario. But apps like chrome,vs etc closes when we do this

Comment: @mot No, it will not

Comment: @PatrickHofman please check : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_7#Thumbnail_previews and http://lifehacker.com/5262386/middle-click-to-close-applications-from-windows-7s-taskbar

Comment: @Zigma So you want to make your app close on middle click? Why change how windows works? I find this very strange that one app will act different on the task bar

Comment: @mot I think you should read the links I provided above. Closing via middle button is default from win7 on wards.But I see the WPF apps not getting closed

Comment: @Zigma Wow so THUMBNAIL middle click closes... freaky stuff. Yep what I said is irrelevant :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had came Across Same issue When I tried to do  the same thing(closing of application) when i was on a window which is not my Mainwindow(or Startup URI) object.So Its my advice that please handle the on closing event of your secondary window(other than Mainwindow)  and tried to shutdown or exit your application by below code

```
private void DataWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  Application.Current.Shutdown();
  // Environment.Exit();
}
```

Wpf automatically Shut downs application when you are on Mainwindow and tried to exit the application.

Comment: This is something I knew and using in my code and I noted it in my question itself. Sounds like no other method for the same. So accepting the answer.